# Como criar um executável " *.exe" em Python?

Tags: python, .exe

Preciso transformar arquivos " *.py" em executáveis " *.exe" para serem executados em qualquer desktop Windows.

Atualmente uso o Python 3.3

Comment: Amigo, só incluir o upix e a opção onefile

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Eu gostaria de deixar registrada a minha sugestão para [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) ou então [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Em todo caso nenhum deles tem como garantir que vai rodar em qualquer desktop Windows.

Em primeiro lugar se você estiver usando Windows 7 64 bit por exemplo para gerar os executáveis, eles não vão rodar em Windows 7 32 bit, mas o contrario sim.

Porém, se você estiver usando Windows 64 bit com Python 32 bit, os arquivos gerados serão 32 bit, e funcionarão no Windows 32 bit e também 64 bit.

Em todo caso vale a pena testar se o programa abre. Pode ser que não funcione em Windows mais antigos que XP. Ainda mais se o seu programa depende de outras bibliotecas como o QT.

Uma outra opção promissora é o [PyOxidizer](https://pyoxidizer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Ele é mais novo, ou seja, é mais moderno, mas ainda está em fase de desenvolvimento - imaturo. Vale à pena testar e ficar de olho.

Recentemente eu tive sucesso com o [Shiv](https://shiv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Ele zipa o seu aplicativo e dependências que você instalou com o `pip` em um arquivo só e usa a funcionalidade do Python `zipapp`. Em termos práticos, você manda para o usuário um só arquivo, mas tem que pedir para ele instalar o Python no computador antes de roda-lo pela primeira vez. É um pouco inconveniente para o usuário, mas eu acho que vale à pena só porque o arquivo fica bem menor. Isso facilita a vida de todo mundo na hora de atualizar por exemplo.

Comment: mas como eu utilizo o cx_freeze para criar os executaveis...não entendi bem o funcionamento deste aplicativo

Answer (score 12):

Para essa versão específica o [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) resolve seu problema. Para versões anteriores, existem essas alternativas: [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), [bbfreeze](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze/)

Answer (score 7):

`pyinstaller` é legal e simples de usar. Primeiro você deve usar um gerenciador de pacotes - provavelmente o `pip` - para instalá-lo

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Após a instalação, basta executa-lo:

```
pyinstaller -w nome_do_software
```

Ou
pyinstaller nome_do_software.py

Para obter o resultado desejado.

Comment: Atualmente existe um forma melhor de efetuar a conversão para exe ?