# Como transformar um arquivo python em executável?

Tags: python, .exe

Se eu criar um aplicativo em python e quiser que outras pessoas possam usá-lo, as outras pessoas vão ter que instalar o python pra poder rodar ele ou existe uma forma de tornar  ele executável? E pra criar um instalador pra esse aplicativo preciso aprender outra linguagem?

Comment: Cara, da uma olhada neste tópico e veja se te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13806/como-criar-um-executavel-exe-em-python

Comment: Ajuda sim, valeu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o cython também. Existe algum ganho de perfomace.

```
cython main_script.py --embed
```

Porém acho que a solução mais simples é utilizar o PyInstaller, funciona no Windows, Linux e MacOS. Ele cria um pacote com tudo incluso(python, libs, e o executavel).

```
pyinstaller main_script.py
```