# Converter Python em exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

tenho um app feito em python que puxa vários imports, e meu cliente não quer instalar o Python em seu ambiente (por se tratar de um servidor Oracle), a saida que eu achei foi a de criar um .exe porém quando eu crio o mesmo (usando o pyinstaller) ao tentar fazer o teste no Windows ele não abre (da que o arquivo não é reconhecido), uso uma disto linux com:

1. Python 2.7
2. Python 3.5
3. Python 3.8

Segue os importa que uso na aplicação

```
import glob, os, time, datetime
```

PS: Ao fazer o teste no windows eu copio tanto a pasta dist quando a build.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

@EDIT

Seguindo a dica, fiz o mesmo processo (CMD > pyinstaller Arq.py), agora o windows chega até a reconhecer porém ao tentar executar apresenta o erro abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Ao executar o Python em si, ele executa de bboa o script (esse script se conecta no banco de dados e pega algumas informações)

Comment: Acredito que seria ideal você colocar os passos de como gerou esse `exe` também.

Comment: Você usou o pyinstaller no disto linux com wine? Se não ele compila somente para linux... Pois o pyinstaller utiliza alguns arquivos nativos do Sistema Operacional para gerar o executável.

Comment: danieltakeshi valeu pela dica, vou subir uma VM com o python e instalar o pyinstall nela e fazer o teste jaja coloco aqui o retorno

Comment: A solução do problema deve estar na área de **respostas**, não na pergunta, bem como colocar "RESOLVIDO" no título é desnecessário, visto que você já aceitou uma resposta, indicando que ela resolveu o problema.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar um executavel " \*.exe" em python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13806/como-criar-um-executavel-exe-em-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O pyinstaller gera executáveis para windows, se executado no windows. Ao rodar o pyinstaller no linux, ele vai gerar um executável pra linux.

Uma forma de contornar isso é usar o wine. Crie um novo prefixo e instale o python, as libs que você quer e o pyinstaller, assim você pode gerar executáveis no linux e usar no windows.

Lembrando que o que o pyinstaller faz é colocar o python e todas as libs dentro do exe, então se o seu cliente não quer instalar o python, é pior pra ele pois cada .exe vai ter o python dentro.

EDIT:

Parece que agora você está usando o Python 3.7 no windows - Parece que tem um [bug no pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3219) nessa versão do python - tente usar o Python 3.6;

Comment: Fala man blz? acabei de editar o artigo informando sobre o teste que fiz e o erro que surgiu

Comment: No meu caso, eu fiz o teste na VM.

Comment: @WallaceBrunoGentil editei a resposta

Comment: Cara resolveu o problema vlw! Vou editar a pergunta e colocar o que foi feito

Comment: @WallaceBrunoGentil sem problemas! Só aceitar a resposta e votar pra cima!