# Gerar executável com mais de um arquivo .py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Boa noite pessoal. Fiz um pequeno projeto em Python e estou tentando gerar o executável. Porém, não encontro nenhum tutorial que ensine a fazer isso com mais de um arquivo junto. No caso do meu projeto, tenho 4 arquivos .py e só consigo gerar o executável de um deles (que, inclusive, dá erro). É possível fazer a junção dos 4 ou algo do tipo para que eu consiga gerar o executável sem ter que junta-los manualmente os códigos em um único arquivo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, você pode usar o pyinstaller que é uma ferramenta própria para esse tipo de trabalho. Dê uma olhada nessa parte da documentação: [Multipackage Bundles](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html#multipackage-bundles). Aconselho tentar o comando no terminal, no diretório de seu projeto: `pyinstaller --onefile main.py` (Coloque o arquivo principal). Provavelmente você precisará instalar o pyinstaller: [How to Install](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html).

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste vídeo: [pyinstaller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBdRfrWT7Co)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como criar um executavel " \*.exe" em python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13806/como-criar-um-executavel-exe-em-python)

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do mateusnss, também há a versão gráfica do pyinstaller, que é o [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/).

Answer (score 0):

Posso te ajudar?

**instale o PyInstaller via pip:**
[FONTE](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/)

pip install PyInstaller

e via terminal ou pront de comando (cmd)

digite essa instrução:

pyinstaller -F -w arquivoPYTHON.py